# Aspxradiobutton passes Null pointer exception

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I'm using dev express with asp.net on a project that requires a radio button and dropdownlist in ASPxGridView. I use the radio button in the edit form. When I save the `<insertparameter>` in `<asp:objectdatasource>` throws a null value.

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="gvEmp" ClientInstanceName="gvEmp" runat="server" 
Width="100%" KeyFieldName="Emp_id" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<columns>
 <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Gender" ShowInCustomizationForm="true" 
  FieldName="Gender"> </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
</columns>
<editform>
  <dx:ASPxRadioButtonList ID="Gender1" AutoPostBack="false" runat="server" 
   Value='<%# Eval("Gender") %>' ValueType="System.String">
   <Items>
   <dx:ListEditItem Text="Male"  Value="Male" Selected="true"/>
   <dx:ListEditItem Text="Female" Value="Female" />
   </Items>
</dx:ASPxRadioButtonList>
</editform>
</dx:ASPxGridView>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDSEmployee" runat="server" 
InsertMethod="InsertEmployee" 
TypeName="solution.file1.DataAccess.InspectionDataAccess">
<InsertParameters>
  <asp:Parameter Name="Gender" Type="String"/>
</InsertParameters>            
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

The Object Data Source Passes a null value to the InsertEmployee method.

Comment: information is not sufficient to understand the issue. Either provide some code or sample to elaborate the behavior..

Comment: This is just a sample code. I am not getting the value from other controls as well like the ASPxComboBox and  ASPxMemo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I used Eval() instead of Bind() in the Radio Button. After I changed it works properly.